# FreeRTOS is not solving my problem to run tasks parallelly

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, spi

I'm pretty new to esp32 and I'm trying to combine two codes in one, they are simple codes from projects that I found online, the first one uses PIR sensor to send message to telegram each time motion is detected, second code uses RFID to open door lock. When I tried directly merging the two codes together the esp32 went crazy on serial monitor and nothing worked even the WIFI failed to connect.

Then I tried creating task for each one using freeRTOS and I did it like this:

***task1***: *for* Wifi connection **running on CORE 0** //wifi function is taken from sketch 1

***task2***: *for* RFID and door lock **running on CORE 1** //taken from sketch 2

***task3***: *for* motion detection and sending telegram message **running on CORE 0** //taken from sketch 1

Again esp32 went crazy when I opened serial monitor and it gave me this error:`" Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled. "`

I have no clue why is this happening, does it really require RTOS to combine the two sketches and run them at the same time, or a simple delays and if statements would solve the problem? I need some help please.

**Sketch 1: Motion detection** from [enter link description here](https://RandomNerdTutorials.com/telegram-esp32-motion-detection-arduino/)

```
/*
  Rui Santos
  Complete project details at https://RandomNerdTutorials.com/telegram-esp32-motion-detection-arduino/
  
  Project created using Brian Lough's Universal Telegram Bot Library: https://github.com/witnessmenow/Universal-Arduino-Telegram-Bot
*/

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <UniversalTelegramBot.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SSID";
const char* password = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PASSWORD";

// Initialize Telegram BOT
#define BOTtoken "XXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"  // your Bot Token (Get from Botfather)

// Use @myidbot to find out the chat ID of an individual or a group
// Also note that you need to click "start" on a bot before it can
// message you
#define CHAT_ID "XXXXXXXXXX"

WiFiClientSecure client;
UniversalTelegramBot bot(BOTtoken, client);

const int motionSensor = 27; // PIR Motion Sensor
bool motionDetected = false;

// Indicates when motion is detected
void IRAM_ATTR detectsMovement() {
  //Serial.println("MOTION DETECTED!!!");
  motionDetected = true;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // PIR Motion Sensor mode INPUT_PULLUP
  pinMode(motionSensor, INPUT_PULLUP);
  // Set motionSensor pin as interrupt, assign interrupt function and set RISING mode
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(motionSensor), detectsMovement, RISING);

  // Attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  Serial.print("Connecting Wifi: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  client.setCACert(TELEGRAM_CERTIFICATE_ROOT); // Add root certificate for api.telegram.org
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, "Bot started up", "");
}

void loop() {
  if(motionDetected){
    bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, "Motion detected!!", "");
    Serial.println("Motion Detected");
    motionDetected = false;
  }
}
```

**Sketch 2: RFID door lock** from [enter link description here](https://esp32io.com/tutorials/esp32-rfid-nfc-door-lock-system)

```
/*
 * This ESP32 code is created by esp32io.com
 *
 * This ESP32 code is released in the public domain
 *
 * For more detail (instruction and wiring diagram), visit https://esp32io.com/tutorials/esp32-rfid-nfc-door-lock-system
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN    5  // ESP32 pin GIOP5 
#define RST_PIN   27 // ESP32 pin GIOP27 
#define RELAY_PIN 22 // ESP32 pin GIOP22 connects to relay

MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

byte keyTagUID[4] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin(); // init SPI bus
  rfid.PCD_Init(); // init MFRC522
  pinMode(RELAY_PIN, OUTPUT); // initialize pin as an output.
  digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH); // lock the door

  Serial.println("Tap an RFID/NFC tag on the RFID-RC522 reader");
}

void loop() {
  if (rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) { // new tag is available
    if (rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) { // NUID has been readed
      MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = rfid.PICC_GetType(rfid.uid.sak);

      if (rfid.uid.uidByte[0] == keyTagUID[0] &&
          rfid.uid.uidByte[1] == keyTagUID[1] &&
          rfid.uid.uidByte[2] == keyTagUID[2] &&
          rfid.uid.uidByte[3] == keyTagUID[3] ) {
        Serial.println("Access is granted");
        digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);  // unlock the door for 2 seconds
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH); // lock the door
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.print("Access denied, UID:");
        for (int i = 0; i < rfid.uid.size; i++) {
          Serial.print(rfid.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
          Serial.print(rfid.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
        }
        Serial.println();
      }

      rfid.PICC_HaltA(); // halt PICC
      rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1(); // stop encryption on PCD
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need an RTOS to do something simple like:

```
if (motionDetected)
    open_the_door ();
```

---

You basically have two loops:

```
void loop ()
  {
  if (motionDetected)
      send_a_message_to_open_the_door ();
  }
```

And:

```
void loop ()
  {
  if (message_received_to_open_the_door)
     open_the_door();
  }
```

So, you combine them into a single loop:

```
void loop ()
  {
  if (motionDetected)
     open_the_door();
  }
```

I'll leave you to make the actual code changes.